# Message Sent time incorrect using javax mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

greetings all
i have a problem that when sending an email from the server to the client using javax mail
and set the sentDate to

```
message.setSentDate(new Date());
```

the email is sent in the server time
and the client receive the email immediately with time 5 hours ago ????
how to fix this to send and receive in correct timing ?

Comment: Maybe the timezone should be consider ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a server incorrect time problem i set the time and the timezone to GMT and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You might have to consider the timezones of client and the server and do the necessary calculation (usually done in the client end).

Comment: it was a server incorrect time problem
i set the time and the timezone to GMT and it works fine now