# java mail sent date was not set correctly

Tags: java, email

I can send mail in my java webapplication,it works fine but,sent date was not set correctly,it was set 18hours advance for example

if we send mail in 27-08-2015 10:00:00, mail was reached immediatly but send date was set as 28-08-2015 03:00:00 like this

below is my java code

```
 public void sendMail(String subject, String body, String recipients, String cc)    {
 try {
       String instructions = "<br><br><br>This is an auto generated mail. Kindly do not reply to this mail. Any reply to this mail will not be monitored or entertained.";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtpout.secureserver.net");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.user", "user");
        props.setProperty("mail.password", "password");
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        body += instructions;
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("guruprasad.n@clss.in"));

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(body, "text/html");
//            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
//            Date dateInString = new Date();
//            // To TimeZone Asia/Calcutta
//            SimpleDateFormat sdfAsia = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
//            TimeZone tzInAsia = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
//            sdfAsia.setTimeZone(tzInAsia);
//
//            String sDateInAsia = sdfAsia.format(dateInString); // Convert to String first
//            Date dateInAsia = formatter.parse(sDateInAsia);
            message.setSentDate(new Date());


            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0) {
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        } else {
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        }
        if (!cc.isEmpty()) {
            if (cc.indexOf(',') > 0) {
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));
            } else {
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc));
            }
        }
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);

        transport.connect("smtpout.secureserver.net", "user", "password");
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        if (!cc.isEmpty()) {
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC));
        }

        transport.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
//            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I can user asia timezone also but it deosn't work Please help me

Thanks

Comment: See this relevant [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052778/message-sent-time-incorrect-using-javax-mail) could it be the same cause/resolution ?

Comment: Sender and receiver are in different timezones?

Comment: You should try without setting any date

Comment: Test once with a different host server.

Answer (score 1):

In most probability the problem lies with your mail server timezone

> smtpout.secureserver.net

You have setSendDate per your local timezone, but your server maybe in another timezone and it resets/modifies the time assuming it is correcting the time.